# Jenkins plugin gitChangelog: how to specyfy repository path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

### Background

I've inherited some messy Jenkins pipeline.
One of the problems is custom plugin which fetches code and creates changelog which always shows difference to previous build (even when previous one was failing).
As a result not all JIRA-s are merked as resolved if there was a failing build.

### Problem

I need to create changelog which is able to take difference against tag indicating last successful build. Fetching tag name and pointing out `from` `to` is not a problem.
Problem is that this custom plugin clones repository to custom path and I do not see any parameter in `gitChangelog` plugin which can allow me to point where actual repository is.

As a result this part of my pipeline:

```
    def changelogString = gitChangelog returnType: 'STRING',
        repository: repoPath,
        from: [type: 'REF', value: "$lastTagName"],
        to: [type: 'REF', value: 'HEAD'],
        template: changesReportTemplate
```

Ends with exception:

```
se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.exceptions.GitChangelogRepositoryException: Did not find a GIT repo in C:\Jenkins\workspace\MyBuildPipelineName
```

I'm unable to find way to provide location of my repository to [gitChangelog](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin) plugin.

Cloning repository to this default location for now is not an option (there was problem with "to long paths").

Answer (score 1):

In a situation similar to yours, we use one job that builds and tests everything, and another one which adds git tags and closes JIRA issues. The build job, when all pre-conditions are met, triggers the other job. Once the tag-and-jira job is running, it discovers the changes since the last time *the tag-and-jira job* was run, and so it operates on all commits from the last successful run. This doesn't miss any JIRA issues due to failing builds or other problems in the build job.

Comment: I should come up with this solution my self, since other issue I've resolved in this way. This will do the job for sure. Still I'm hoping to use `gitChangelog` anyway.